# "on a scale of 1 to 10"?

Tags: words

How can I say "on a scale of 1 to 10"?

Like for example,

"On a scale of 1 to 10 where 1 is not annoying at all and 10 is too annoying, how annoying do you find X"?

Answer (score 6):

You can say 「10点満点{てんまんてん}で」.

More "formally", you can say 「10段階評価{だんかいひょうか}で」.

Both are very common.

Comment: 十点満点で、朝の早いにうるさい人に起きられるって、どれぐらいイライラですか？Or how would I make a sentence with it?

Comment: Using 10点満点 usually means 10点 is the best thing (満点 = full marks). Something like "1から10で言うとどのくらい?" would be better when you want to measure irritation/pain/sleepiness/etc.

Comment: @ナウシカ 「どれぐらいイライラですか」 might make you sound cuter in this case, but you'd usually say 「イライラしますか」 or 「イライラを感じますか」.

Comment: @naruto Thank you for your comment. I feel that I didn't get the full picture from l'électeur's answer. Is it really 10で言うと、not　10まで？

Comment: @broccoliforest Thank you for your comment. Do you mean cuter because it's broken Japanese?

Comment: @ナウシカ 「イライラ」 belongs to verb (-する) if you want to conjugate it, but since it's a mimetic word, using it as other than verb doesn't immediately violate the grammar, just sound like you're replacing some ordinary word with the mimetic, which I imagine is the way how girls talk (jocularly). 朝早くにうるさい人に起きられる（の）って、1から10で言えばどれぐらいイライラします（か）？